# docker mount - Error response from daemon: invalid mount config for type "bind"

Tags: docker, docker-run

I am facing an issue with mounting a host directory into docker container with both -v and --mount options.

**Using mount:**

```
docker run --mount type=bind,source=/home/myuser/docker_test/out_dir,target=/home/out_dir --user 12345:1000 -it docker-name:0.1 bash
docker: Error response from daemon: invalid mount config for type "bind": stat /home/myuser/docker_test/out_dir: permission denied.
```

But I am able to do stat on this directory.

```
stat /home/myuser/docker_test/out_dir
  File: '/home/myuser/docker_test/out_dir'
  Size: 4096            Blocks: 8          IO Block: 32768  directory
Device: 33h/51d Inode: 9275022755226025350  Links: 2
Access: (0770/drwxrwx---)  Uid: (12345/  myuser)   Gid: ( 1000/    hercules)
Access: 2022-12-01 02:12:54.430582000 -0500
Modify: 2022-12-01 02:12:38.239629000 -0500
Change: 2022-12-01 02:12:38.239629000 -0500
 Birth: -
```

**Using -v:**

```
docker run -v /home/myuser/docker_test/out_dir:/home/out_dir --user 12345:1000 -it docker-name:0.1:0.1 bash
docker: Error response from daemon: error while creating mount source path '/home/myuser/docker_test/out_dir': mkdir /home/myuser/docker_test: permission denied.
ERRO[0000] error waiting for container: context canceled
```

I don't know why it's trying to do mkdir but /home/myuser/docker_test already exists and is writable for the current user.

Am I missing something here?
BTW - /home is a NFS mounted directory.

**EDIT**: mounting /tmp worked. So this means it is related to the NFS mounted directory /home.

**EDIT 2**
I am working on a network machine where I don’t have root (sudo) access.
The docker service is installed by root user.
/home/myuser/docker_test/out_dir has 700 (rwx------) permissions. If I change the permission to 755, it will work. But I can’t change the directory permissions.

My question is why stat is failing when the user starting the docker has the permissions to access the source directory?
Is the stat being called by the docker executable as some ‘other’ user?

Comment: I was hit by the same problem, and I have the same guess, that it has to do with the docker daemon's permissions, before it drops its privileges to the `--user`.

Answer (score -1):

Use:

```
sudo docker run -v /home/myuser/docker_test/out_dir:/home/out_dir --user 12345:1000 -it docker-name:0.1:0.1 bash
```

Comment: I don't have sudo permissions on this machine.